# JS function never gets triggered when I use @Scripts.Render. Normal call works fine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**This code:**

```
PDFJS.getDocument(parameters).then(
  function getDocumentCallback(pdfDocument) {          
    self.load(pdfDocument, scale);
    self.loading = false;
  }
```

is supposed to call this function:

```
PDFJS.getDocument = function getDocument(source) {
return alert('never gets here');
 var workerInitializedPromise, workerReadyPromise, transport;
if (typeof source === 'string') {
  source = { url: source };
  return alert('string');
} else if (isArrayBuffer(source)) {
  source = { data: source };
  return alert('data');
} else if (typeof source !== 'object') {
  return alert('erro');
error('Invalid parameter in getDocument, need either Uint8Array, ' +
      'string or a parameter object');
}

 if (!source.url && !source.data) {
  error('Invalid parameter array, need either .data or .url');
  return alert('erro 2');
}

// copy/use all keys as is except 'url' -- full path is required
var params = {};
for (var key in source) {      
  if (key === 'url' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  params[key] = combineUrl(window.location.href, source[key]);
  continue;
}
params[key] = source[key];

}
 workerInitializedPromise = new PDFJS.Promise();
    workerReadyPromise = new PDFJS.Promise();
  transport = new WorkerTransport(workerInitializedPromise, workerReadyPromise);
 workerInitializedPromise.then(function transportInitialized() {
    transport.fetchDocument(params);
    });
    return workerReadyPromise;
  };
```

Although if I use

```
@Scripts.Render("~/PDF/js")
```

to call the script instead of use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Url.Content("~/pdf.js/api.js")"> </script>
```

The function `PDFJS.getDocument` never gets triggered.

Am I missing somenthing?

**edit:** both cases the js file is loaded. Just the function is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have in the corresponding `~/PDF/js` bundle? Did you make sure that all the necessary scripts are included and in the correct order?

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/PDF/js").Include("~/pdf/api.js")
);
```

Also take a look at what does the `@Script.Render` method outputs in the resulting HTML page. Since bundles are not minified, nor combined in Debug mode you should be able to see the `<script>` references to each of the files you need. Now compare those references with those that you would normally use without any bundles or even ASP.NET MVC. How do they differ?

Also I've noticed that you have used quite a strange path in your Url.Content helper: `~/pdf.js/api.js`. Are you sure that this works?